# Why is the following code giving me a declaration error in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use the following module:

https://github.com/andyhu/transliteration

When I try:

```
import { transliterate as tr, slugify } from 'transliteration';
```

I get:

```
error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'transliteration'.
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: You're getting that message because TypeScript could not find a declaration file. Looking at that GitHub link, the author does not seem to have provided one, so you'll need to provide your own. See [How do you produce a .d.ts "typings" definition file from an existing JavaScript library?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12687779)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I fix this error?

Because the package does not ship with TypeScript type definitions.

## Fix

Try `npm install @types/transliteration` and if that doesn't work [simply create](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/migrating.html):

```
declare module 'translitereation';
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** The types are now available from `DefinitelyTyped`. Just run the following command to resolve the type errors:

```
npm i -D @types/transliteration
```

<del>That GitHub project has no public typings, so you'd have to create your own local typings in your project (see *Quick Fix* below). I have a [`DefinitelyTyped` PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/25542) open to publish new typings so that you'd be able to install them (with `npm i @types/transliteration`) instead of maintaining your own.</del>

---

*Quick Fix:* create `<project-root>/index.d.ts` with the following contents:

```
declare module 'transliteration' {
  function transliterate(str: string, options?: transliterate.Options): string;

  namespace transliterate {
    /**
    * Bind options globally so any following calls will be using
    * optionsObj by default. If optionsObj argument is omitted,
    * it will return current default option object.
    */
    function config(optionsObj?: Options): Options;

    interface Options {

      /**
      * Unicode characters that are not in the database will be replaced with `unknown`
      * default: "[?]"
      */
      unknown?: string;

      /**
      * Custom replacement of the strings before transliteration
      */
      replace?: string[][] |  {[source: string]: string};

      /**
      * Strings in the ignore list will be bypassed from transliteration
      */
      ignore?: string[];
    }
  }

  function slugify(str: string, options?: slugify.Options): string;

  namespace slugify {
    /**
    * Bind options globally so any following calls will be using
    * optionsObj by default. If optionsObj argument is omitted,
    * it will return current default option object.
    */
    function config(optionsObj?: Options): Options;

    interface Options {

      /**
      * Whether to force slugs to be lowercased
      * default: true
      */
      lowercase?: boolean;

      /**
      * Separator of the slug
      * default: "-"
      */
      separator?: string;

      /**
      * Custom replacement of the strings before transliteration
      */
      replace?: string[][] |  {[source: string]: string};

      /**
      * Strings in the ignore list will be bypassed from transliteration
      */
      ignore?: string[];
    }
  }
}
```